# Duda con realizar pedidos en PHP y SQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Edito:

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de un sistema web de gestión de pedidos. He conseguido mostrar la lista de productos con el plugin datatables y todo va genial. El problema es que al ser miles de productos la tabla va muy lenta debido al foreach, he visto que con server-side de datatables va muchísimo más rápido, pero al intentarlo los campos de búsqueda no me funciona y me da error json tn1. Me gustaría saber como puedo implementar el server-side y que siga funcionando los campos de búsqueda.

## lista_producto.php

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['arra'])){

        $_SESSION['arra']=array();

    }

    include "../conexion.php";

    /*$consulta = "SELECT p.REFERENCIA,p.ID,p.TALLA,p.COLOR,
                p.IMAGEN,p.DESCRIPCION,p.PRECIO,pr.PROVEEDOR 
                FROM productos p
                INNER JOIN proveedores pr
                ON p.PROVEEDOR = pr.idproveedor";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conection, $consulta);
    $productos = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_close($conection);*/

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <?php include "includes/script.php"; ?>
    <title>Lista Productos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"?>
    <section id="container">
        <?php
        function arr(){

            if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
                    $nombre=$_GET['id'];
            }else{
                $nombre="";    
            }

                         if($nombre!=""){

                           $_SESSION['arra'][$nombre]=0;

                         }

                         if(!empty($_SESSION)){

                    }

                }
        ?>
        <br>
        <h1>Lista de Productos</h1>

        <a href="registro_producto.php" class="btn_new"> Cargar productos (CSV)</a>

        <table id="productos" class="table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead class="text-center">
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Proveedor</th>
                    <th>Talla</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Pedidos</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
            <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
            </table>
            <?php
            arr();
            ?>

    </section>

    <?php include "includes/footer.php"?>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#productos thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#productos thead' );
    $('#productos thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar '+title+'" />' );
        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    }
     );

    var table = $('#productos').DataTable( {
                "order": [[1, "asc"]],
                "language":{
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                    "info": "",
                    "decimal": ",",
                    "thousands": ".",
                        "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "processing":     "Procesando...",
                        "search": "Buscar:",
                        "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
                        "paginate": {
                            "next":       ">>",
                            "previous":   "<<",
                            "first":       "<|",
                            "last":   "|>"
                        },                  
                    },
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        scrollY:        '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax":{
            url:"server-side-productos.php",
            type:"post"
            },
    } );
} );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

## server-side-productos.php

```php
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','central_uniformes')
    or die("connection failed".mysqli_errno($con));

$request=$_REQUEST;
$col =array(
    0   =>  'REFERENCIA',
    1   =>  'ID',
    2   =>  'PROVEEDOR',
    3   =>  'TALLA',
    4   =>  'COLOR',
    5   =>  'IMAGEN',
    6   =>  'DESCRIPCION',
    7   =>  'PRECIO'
);  //create column like table in database

$sql ="SELECT p.REFERENCIA,p.ID,p.TALLA,p.COLOR,
p.IMAGEN,p.DESCRIPCION,p.PRECIO,pr.PROVEEDOR 
FROM productos p
INNER JOIN proveedores pr
ON p.PROVEEDOR = pr.idproveedor";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$totalData=mysqli_num_rows($query);

$totalFilter=$totalData;

//Search
$sql ="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE 1=1";
if(!empty($request['search']['value'])){
    $sql.=" AND (p.REFERENCIA Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR p.ID Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR pr.PROVEEDOR  Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR p.TALLA Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR p.COLOR Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
    $sql.=" OR p.IMAGEN Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
    $sql.=" OR p.DESCRIPCION Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
    $sql.=" OR p.PRECIO Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$totalData=mysqli_num_rows($query);

//Order
$sql.=" ORDER BY ".$col[$request['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$request['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".
    $request['start']."  ,".$request['length']."  ";

$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$data=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $subdata=array();
    $subdata[]=$row[0]; //id
    $subdata[]=$row[1]; //name
    $subdata[]=$row[2]; //salary
    $subdata[]=$row[3]; //age           //create event on click in button edit in cell datatable for display modal dialog           $row[0] is id in table on database
    $subdata[]=$row[4];
    $subdata[]=$row[5];
    $subdata[]=$row[6];
    $subdata[]=$row[7];
    /*$subdata[]='<button type="button" id="getEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="'.$row[0].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</i>Edit</button>
                <a href="index.php?delete='.$row[0].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are You Sure ?\')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">&nbsp;</i>Delete</a>';*/



    if(!empty($_SESSION['arra'])){

        $diferente=0;

    foreach( $_SESSION['arra'] as $key=>$value) {

        if($row[1]!=$key){

            $diferente=$diferente+1;                

        }

    }

    if($diferente==count($_SESSION['arra'])){

        $subdata[]= " 

        <form action='lista_producto.php' method='get' class='form_search'>

        <input type='submit'  class='btnAdd' value='Agregar' name='btn_add' >

        <input type='hidden' value='$row[1]' name='id'>

        </form>";

    }else{

        $subdata[]= " 

        <form action='lista_producto.php' method='get' class='form_search'>

        <input type='submit'  class='btnDel' value='Carrito' name='btn_add' >

        <input type='hidden' value='$row[1]' name='id'>

        </form>";

    }

}else{

    $subdata[]= " 

        <form action='lista_producto.php' method='get' class='form_search'>

        <input type='submit'  class='btnAdd' value='Agregar' name='btn_add' >

        <input type='hidden' value='$row[1]' name='id'>

        </form>";

}

$data[]=$subdata;
}

$json_data=array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($request['draw']),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  intval($totalData),
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  intval($totalFilter),
    "data"              =>  $data
);

echo json_encode($json_data);

?>
```

Comment: 2 cosas, la primera para recibir un parámetro enviado por URL debes usar `$_GET['id']`, luego en `$producto["id"]` seria mejor hacerlo con `$producto['id']` porque las comillas cierran el href según veo.

Comment: Buenas, disculpa la tardanza he tenido unos días algo liosos, he estado mirando lo que me dijiste pero sigo sin dar con ello, además de probar otros métodos, podrías ponerme algún ejemplo? muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Me he percatado de que los `<td>` no llevan el punto y coma
`<?php echo $producto['PRECIO']?>` y el `href` si `<?php echo $producto["REFERENCIA"];?>`. ¿Has probado a quitarlo?

Comment: Gracias Elias, he resuelto el pasar las variables, pero ahora no consigo que se quede almacenado en el otro php, he editado la pregunta actualizando el código

Comment: Una acotación , hablas de un problema con SESSION, he iniciaste una instancia pero no veo que estés guardando variables en dicha instancia algo así como   $_SESSION['nombreUsuario']=$row['nombre']; y claro el detalle con las sesiones es que sus variables solo están activas mientras la instancia esta iniciada, pero para un carrito de compras no debería haber problemas.

Answer (score 2):

## Posibles Mejoras.

Te recomiendo que para este proyecto lo hagas separando todo en controladores, vistas y middlewares sin necesidad de llegar a ser un MVC, ademas de usar POO para poder tener mas control sobre cada uno de los procesos y utilizar Ajax para las funciones dinamicas como:

- Productos
- Productos en carrito de compras
- Historicos

Con esto puedes tener mas ordenado tu codigo y detectar de manera mas segura los posibles errores.

## Solución al problema.

- Toda la información sensible que pases de una vista a otra pasalas por `$_POST[]` con esto te aseguras de que no sea manipulada de forma maliciosa
- Tu carrito de compras deberia ser una clase externa que se llena de forma dinamica con la informacion que se almacena en alguna variable global
- Para almacenar la información de tu carrito de compras lo puedes hacer tres maneras
  - Tal cual como lo estas haciendo desde $_SESSION[] sin embargo esto limita a que el carrito solo sea visible con la sesion activa y pudiera generarte algun problema de UX
  - Haciendo uso de una cookie que contenga ya sea un arreglo o un JSON con la informacion, en lo personal, yo haria una $_COOKIE[] que me almacene todos los ID de los productos que guarde temporalmente en el carrito
  - Almacenando información temporal en una tabla de tu base de datos con la cual al momento de almacenar algo en tu carrito lo que hagas sea guardar datos como `[idProducto,color,talla,marca,...,Cantidad]` con lo cual la información sea accesible para todos los controladores.

En lo personal me inclinaria por la ultima opcion aunque obviamente consumiria mas espacio, aunque lo puedes ver por el lado de recoleccion de informacion en donde a futuro puedes generar estadisticas sobre *cantidad de articulos en carrito por usuario* VS *Cantidad de articulos comprados por usuario* o incluso calcular una media del tiempo en que un articulo se la pasa en el carrito, asi tampoco saturarias el almacenamiento del navegador (ademas recuerda que si guardas algo desde el lado del navegador puedes perderlo cuando el usuario borre las cookies o sesiones)

## Consideraciones finales.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo dicho anteriormente creo que tu problema es de seleccion de opciones para mejorar el rendimiento de tu sistema, trata de mejorar la disposicion de tu codigo para que con ello puedas hacer un sistema mas integral y escalable y considera el almacenamiento temporal de la informacion del carrito en una tabla.

Espero haberte ayudado a encontrar un camino a seguir o bien a encontrar la solucion a tu problema.

Si tienes dudas con gusto las aclarare.

Comment: Muchas gracias Iván, soy nuevo en PHP y por eso ando algo perdido, he leído lo que me has dicho y es cierto que es mejor así, el caso es que me cuesta un poco desarrollar todo esto pero seguiré tu consejo a ver si consigo avanzar algo.

Comment: Claro, con gusto te seguire apoyando en futuras preguntas.

Comment: Gracias Iván, el problema que tengo ahora es otro, intento cambiar el método de listar los productos a server-side, ya que con el foreach carga muy lento, pero al hacerlo los campos de búsqueda no funcionan y me da error tn1 de json.

Comment: Todos tus archivos que tengan etiquetas HTML y muestren información interpretada van del lado del cliente osea que son vistas, en todo caso si tú JSON está llegando o enviándose desde tu listado trata de mandarlo como JSON stringify (este método es se JS así que provecha el Ajax que tienes)

Comment: Podrías ponerme algún ejemplo? Es que cuando ejecuto el programa, todo va bien y me muestra los datos perfectamente, el problema es al intentar buscar en alguno de los campos de búsqueda me tira ese error y sé que tiene que ver con algún error del archivo server side pero no sé exactamente donde.

Comment: Claro solo edita tu pregunta y pon tu arbol de directorios para saber decirte como deberia ir y como se deberia instanciar

Comment: Vale gracias, lo edité antes de responderte, lo del árbol de directorios no entendí muy bien pero está todo fuera en la misma carpeta.

Comment: Tu arbol de directorios es el orden de carpetas y archivos

Comment: Creo que encontre tu error, en tu ajax debex agregar la opcion `data : { search:{value:valor_busqueada}},` espero que eso sea claro